# Exporting modular objects to Substance Painter for baking

Tags: baking

I do want to create modular assets within Blender which I use to assemble the full model. I want to bake the high poly version onto the low poly version. It does work for the modular assets alone like this in substance painter:

[image]

But I do enjoy seeing the fully assembled asset in Substance Paitner, as it makes painting much easier. But if I export a copy (or several) of the modular assets (*as fbx), baking does not work any more. Here with a simple wall out of the stone.

Blender:

[image]

Result in Substance Painter:

[image]

I can bake the modular assets first and then import the modular assets with the assembled version. This does work, but it feels like it's a kinda hacky workflow. This is the result (with my baking information):

[image]

How can I export my modular assets together with the finished asset and bake it in Substance Painter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did work, when I moved all the UVs of the assembled asset by 1 to the right.

[image]